# Buddyboss Platform plugin causing "too many redirects"

Tags: redirect

Last week, I moved my wordpress site from a temporary domain with bluehost to the normal domain ([www.cozygigs.com](http://www.cozygigs.com)). On the temporary domain, everything worked properly.

After I did so, I became unable to load the home page on any device because of "too many redirects."

When I isolated each plugin I was able to verify that it's the buddyboss platform plugin that is causing this issue. When said plugin is deactivated the site loads properly. That said, I *need* the buddyboss platform because professional networking is why my site exists. I need the functions this plug offers.

When using a redirect tracer tool I can see that when the homepage loads it starts and endless chain of 302 redirects.

I have tried basic fixes like making sure the URLs match in WP settings.

I would sincerely appreciate any help you can offer. I have searched high and low in the dashboard for some setting that would cause this but I can't find it.

Thanks for your time!
Andrew

EDIT: OK -- got it working again thanks to a helpful tech support member at Buddyboss. Here's what I did for anyone else with the same issue: 1) Enable the plugin 2) Go into the buddyboss platform privacy settings, disable the "private network" and save 3) Re-enable the private network, while whitelisting the home URL and login pages, then save 4) Clear cache It works!!! Thanks to all who generously offered their help today!!!! It means a lot.

Comment: With the plugin active (ie. when the problem exists) post the contents of your htaccess file. This question may be off-topic on WPSE and too specific to one particular plugin but if there is a simple answer to an htaccess problem you may get it here :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am a novice to WP but I know how to get what you're looking for.

BTW I had an earlier issue with the site and it seems there are multiple .htaccess files. Should I delete the older ones? (sorry if this is something obvious)

the most recent .htaccess is called .htaccess33 and its contents are as follows:

Comment: Well, I would post the contents but it's over 100 lines long..  too long for this message board's character count?

Comment: I have .htaccess, .htaccess22 and .htaccess33.... should I have all 3 of these?

Comment: Wow yeah that's a lot of lines! Just so you know, you can edit your original question with extra info but maybe not in this case. Don't worry about the 22 and 33 files as they are likely to be backups. One thing you can try is to disable the plugin and then open htaccess again and see if it looks vastly different. That file has only a handful of lines by default. So if that particular plugin is a likely cause, check the file both with and without it activated.

Comment: For reference. Note how lightweight this is normally. Other plugins may write to this file as well though. https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/

Comment: OK, I was able to add the entire .htaccess content into my original post. thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah ok! Question - have you disabled WP Rocket at this point? If not try disabling only that. Or just say if it's off already.

Comment: Just checking as you don't mention, but did you update all the URL's in your database from your old domain to the new domain? This error is often seen when you've missed one somewhere.

Comment: OK -- got it working again thanks to a helpful tech support member at Buddyboss. Here's what I did for anyone else with the same issue:

1) Enable the plugin
2) Go into the buddyboss platform privacy settings, disable the "private network" and save
3) Re-enable the private network, while whitelisting the home URL and login pages, then save
4) Clear cache

It works!!!

Thanks to all who generously offered their help today!!!! It means a lot.

Comment: @Andrew if you want you can add an answer to your question which is then more clearly displayed and better indexed

Comment: Great news that you solved it :)